# jQuery trying to handle ajax failure and sucess not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I had a working jQuery ajax call but i wanted to check the result of the request so i added

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data.status == 'success'){
        alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
    }else if(data.status == 'error'){
        alert("Error on query!");
    }
}
```

but this is not working and made my whole function stop working even.so here is the whole function,can some one tell me what am doing wrong`

```
   function addGoal()  {

    var description = $('.description').val();
    var measure = $('.measure').val();

    if(  description.trim()  &&  measure.trim()  ){
        if(window.confirm("Are you sure? You can't edit or remove goal(s) you have added here.")==true) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '${g.createLink( controller:'review', action:'saveGoal', params:[id: params.id]  )}',
                data: {
                    "description": description,
                    "measure": measure
                },

               success: function(data) {
                    if(data.status == 'success'){
                        alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
                    }else if(data.status == 'error'){
                        alert("Error on query!");
                    }
                }
                type: 'POST'                 
            });
        }
    }else {
        showErrorMessage("Description and Measure fields cant be empty");
    }
}`
```

when i remove the success it works as i expected it to.And if it matters am using grails

Comment: You're missing a `,` after the `}` in the `success` block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax error which is a missing comma

```
   function addGoal()  {

    var description = $('.description').val();
    var measure = $('.measure').val();

    if(  description.trim()  &&  measure.trim()  ){
        if(window.confirm("Are you sure? You can't edit or remove goal(s) you have added here.")==true) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '${g.createLink( controller:'review', dataType: "json", action:'saveGoal', params:[id: params.id]  )}',
                data: {
                    "description": description,
                    "measure": measure
                },

               success: function(data) {
                    if(data.status == 'success'){
                        alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
                    }else if(data.status == 'error'){
                        alert("Error on query!");
                    }
                },
                type: 'POST'                 
            });
        }
    }else {
        showErrorMessage("Description and Measure fields cant be empty");
    }
}`
```

This will fix the issue

Comment: this stopped my function from falling,but still am not able to get success or failure messages.

Comment: If you need a json output, send your ajax request with `dataType: "json"`